# Cannot using React Syntax Highlighter in Next.js 13 & Sanity v3

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, sanity, react-syntax-highlighter

Hello i have a problem for my project using Sanity v3 and React Syntax Highlighter. When i use `Refactor` library for showing my code in the browser it works by looking a tutorial in [Code Input by Sanity](https://www.sanity.io/plugins/code-input)

But when i want to using React Syntax Highlighter and choosing Prism as theme i cannot show it because the error is look like this :

`Server Error TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function`

I am using Next.Js 13 & Typescript and this is my code :

```
import { Prism as SyntaxHighlighter } from "react-syntax-highlighter";
import { dark } from "react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/prism";

types: {
    image: SampleImageComponent,
    code: (props: any) => {
        return (
            <SyntaxHighlighter language={props.value.language} style={dark}>
                {props.value.code}
            </SyntaxHighlighter>
        );
    },
},
```

How can i add React Syntax Highlighter in my project?

Comment: The given code sample does not raise any type error: https://tsplay.dev/mbKMEW

Comment: Yup i dont understand because i want to display in `<PortableText>` Component. So i have to create every type that Sanity allowed to display it whatever i like. If i use `<Refactor>` component from https://github.com/rexxars/react-refractor, it works normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors raise because it should React.FC types like this :

```
interface CodeInputProps {
    code: string;
    language: string;
}

const CodeInput: React.FC<CodeInputProps> = (props) => {
    const { code, language } = props;
    return (
        <SyntaxHighlighter language={language} style={tomorrow}>
            {code}
        </SyntaxHighlighter>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 7):

I found a separate solution to this issue. For me it was because the syntax highlighter runs client side and Next13 out of the box uses server components if you're using the new `app` directory.

Try adding `'use client'` at the top of the file that is using `SyntaxHighlighter`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try importing from 'cjs' as oppose to 'esm' as the code has to be executable from the server side (as mentioned above)

Therefore:

```js
import { dark } from "react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/prism"
```